# How does mutex condition signaling loop works?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, locking, mutex

I will make a hypothetical scenario just to be clear about what I need to know.

Let's say I have a single file being updated very often.

I need to read and parse this file by several different threads.

Everytime this file is rewritten, I'm gonna wake a condition mutex so the other threads can do whatever they want to.

My question is:

If I have 10000 threads, the first thread execution will block the execution of the other 9999 ones?

Does it work in parallel or synchronously?

Comment: "Wake a condition mutex"? That doesn't sound like a standard concept.

Comment: Should I replace wake for broadcast ? like in pthread_cond_broadcast

Comment: Each thread blocks until acquires it acquires the mutex. Then it can operate. Once it is done, it releases its mutex. Then one of the other threads is automatically awakend by the thread scheduler (generally the operating system). You do not have to do this yourself.

Comment: Mutexes by themselves protect a common resource among peers competing for access. Condition variables combine with mutexes to create 'auto reset events', or other kinds of events, for a server/multiple client design. Some OS's, like Windows, have 'Event' objects, but Linux/UNIX use the mutex/condition pairing to do this.

Comment: If the threads only read the file, they should be able to do that in parallel, so you might want to consider a "rw lock" aka shared mutex. That  allows multiple threads to take a "read lock" at once, to perform non-modifying read-only operations in parallel. When you need to update the file you would take the unique "write lock" which only one thread can do at once.

Comment: Also, if you have to ask this question and you really have 10000 threads you should probably read a good book, not try to learn how to do this kind of thing via vague stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Checkout the read-write lock. The read-write locks will be very helpful if architecture is clearly divided into reader and writers, with scenario having more number of reads. That is, the read-write locks allows multiple readers to be in the same critical region and thereby enable you to take advantage in the form of parallel processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post has been edited since first posted to address comments below by Jonathan Wakely, and to better distinguish between a condition_variable, a condition (which were both called condition in the first version), and how the wait function operates. Just as important, however, is an exploration of better methods from modern C++, `using std::future`, `std::thread` and `std::packaged_task`, with some discussion regarding buffering and reasonable thread count.

First, 10,000 threads is a lot of threads. The thread scheduler will be highly burdened on all but the very highest performance of computers. Typical quad core workstations under Windows would struggle. It's a sign that some kind of queued scheduling of tasks is in order, typical of servers accepting thousands of connections using perhaps 10 threads, each servicing 1,000 connects. The number of threads is really not important to the question, but that in such a volume of tasks 10,000 threads is impracticable.

To handle synchronization, the mutex doesn't actually do what you're proposing, by itself. The concept you're describing is a type of event object, perhaps an auto reset event, which by itself is a higher level concept. Windows has them as part of its API, but they are fashioned on Linux (and for portable software, usually) with two primitive components, a mutex and a condition variable. Together these create the auto reset event, and other types of "waitable events" as Windows calls them. In C++ these are provided by `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`.

Mutexes by themselves merely provide locked control over a common resource. In that scenario we are not thinking in terms of clients and a server (or workers and an executive), but we're thinking in terms of competition among peers for a single resource which can only be accessed by one actor (thread) at a time. A mutex can block execution, but it does not release based on an external signal. Mutexes block if another thread has locked the mutex, and wait indefinitely until the owner of the lock releases it. This isn't the scenario you present in the question.

In your scenario, there are many "clients" and one "server" thread. The server is in charge of signalling that something is ready to be processed. All other threads are clients in this design (nothing about the thread itself makes them clients, we merely deem them so by the function they execute). In some discussions, clients are called worker threads.

The clients use a mutex/condition variable pair to wait for a signal. This construct usually takes the form of locking a mutex, then waiting on the condition variable using that mutex. When a thread enters `wait` on the condition variable, the mutex is unlocked. This is repeated for all client threads who wait for work to be done. A typical client wait example is:

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;

void client_thread()
{
    // Wait until server signals data is ready

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);  // lock the mutex

    cv.wait(lk);                         // wait on cv

    // do the work
}
```

This is pseudo code showing the mutex/conditional variable used together. `std::condition_variable` has two overloads of the wait function, this is the simplest one. The intent is that a thread will block, entering into an idle state until the condition_variable is signalled. It is not intended as a complete example, merely to point out these two objects are used together.

Johnathan Wakely's comments below are based on the fact that `wait` is not indefinite; there is no guarantee that the reason the call is unblocked is because of a signal. The documentation calls this a "spurious wakeup", which occasionally occurs for complex reasons of OS scheduling. The point which Johnathan makes is that code using this pair must be safe to operate even if the wakeup is not because the condition_variable was signalled.

In the parlance of using condition variables, this is known as a condition (not the condition_variable). The condition is an application defined concept, usually illustrated as a boolean in the literature, and often the result of checking a bool, an integer (sometimes of atomic type) or calling a function returning a bool. Sometimes application defined notions of what constitutes a true condition are more complex, but the overall effect of the condition is to determine whether or not the thread, once awakened, should continue to process, or should simply repeat the wait.

One way to satisfy this requirement is the second version of std::condition_variable::wait. The two are declared:

```
void wait( std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock );

template< class Predicate >
void wait( std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock, Predicate pred );
```

Johnathan's point is to insist the second version be used. However, documentation describes (and the fact there are two overloads indicates) that the Predicate is optional. The Predicate is a functor of some kind, often a lambda expression, resolving to true if the wait should unblock, false if the wait should continue waiting, and it is evaluated under lock. The Predicate is synonymous with condition in that the Predicate is one way in which to indicate true or false regarding whether wait should unblock.

Although the Predicate is, in fact, optional, the notion that 'wait' is not perfect in blocking until a signal is received requires that if the first version is used, it is because the application is constructed such that spurious wakes have no consequence (indeed, are part of the design).

Jonathan's citation shows that the Predicate is evaluated under lock, but in generalized forms of the paradigm that's frequently not practicable. std::condition_variable must wait on a locked std::mutex, which may be protecting a variable defining the condition, but sometimes that's not possible. Sometimes the condition is more complex, external, or trivial enough that the std::mutex isn't associated with the condition.

To see how that works in the context of the proposed solution, assume there are 10 client threads waiting for a server to signal that work is to be done, and that work is scheduled in a queue as a container of virtual functors. A virtual functor might be something like:

```
struct VFunc
{
 virtual void operator()(){}
};

template <typename T>
struct VFunctor
{
 // Something referring to T, possible std::function
 virtual void operator()(){...call the std::function...}
};

typedef std::deque< VFunc > Queue;
```

The pseudo code above suggests a typical functor with a virtual operator(), returning void and taking no parameters, sometimes known as a "blind call". The key point in suggesting it is the fact Queue can own a collection of these without knowing what is being called, and whatever VFunctors are in Queue could refer to anything std::function might be able to call, which includes member functions of other objects, lambdas, simple functions, etc. If, however, there is only one function signature to be called, perhaps:

```
typedef std::deque< std::function<void(void)>> Queue
```

Is sufficient.

For either case, work is to be done only if there are entries in Queue.

To wait, one might use a class like:

```
class AutoResetEvent
{
 private:
    std::mutex  m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool signalled;
    bool signalled_all;
    unsigned int wcount;

 public:
    AutoResetEvent() : wcount( 0 ), signalled(false), signalled_all(false) {}

    void SignalAll() { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
                       signalled = true;
                       signalled_all = true;
                       cv.notify_all();
                     }
    void SignalOne() { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
                       signalled = true;
                       cv.notify_one();
                     }
    void Wait()      { std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
                       ++wcount;
                       while( !signalled )
                          {
                           cv.wait(l);
                          }
                       --wcount;
                       if ( signalled_all )
                            { if ( wcount == 0 ) 
                                { signalled = false; 
                                  signalled_all = false; 
                                }
                            }
                       else { signalled = false; 
                            }
                     }
};
```

This is pseudo code of a standard reset event type of waitable object, compatible with Windows `CreateEvent` and `WaitForSingleObject` API, functioning the basic same way.

All client threads end up at cv.wait (this can have a timeout in Windows, using the Windows API, but not with `std::condition_variable`). At some point, the server signals the event with a call to Signalxxx. Your scenario suggests `SignalAll()`.

If notify_one is called, one of the waiting threads is released, and all others remain asleep. Of notify_all is called, then all threads waiting on that condition are released to do work.

The following might be an example of using AutoResetEvent:

```
AutoResetEvent evt;   // probably not a global

void client()
{
 while( !Shutdown ) // assuming some bool to indicate shutdown
   {
    if ( IsWorkPending() ) DoWork();
    evt.Wait();
   }
}

void server()
{
 // gather data
 evt.SignalAll();
}
```

The use of `IsWorkPending()` satisfies the notion of a condition, as Jonathan Wakely indicates. Until a shutdown is indidated, this loop will process work if it's pending, and wait for a signal otherwise. Spurious wakeups have no negative effect. `IsWorkPending()` would check `Queue.size()`, possibly through an object which protects Queue with a std::mutex or some other synchronization mechanism. If work is pending, `DoWork()` would sequentially pop entries out of Queue until Queue is empty. Upon return, the loop would again wait for a signal.

With all of that discussed, the combination of mutex and condition_variable is related to an old style of thinking, now outdated in the era of C++11/C++14. Unless you have trouble using a compliant compiler, it would be better to investigate the use of std::promise, std::future and either std::async or std::thread with std::packaged_task. For example, using future, promise, packaged_task and thread could entirely replace the discussion above.

For example:

```
// a function for threads to execute
int func()
{
 // do some work, return status as result
 return result;
}
```

Assuming func does the work you require on the files, these typedefs apply:

```
typedef std::packaged_task< int() >  func_task;
typedef std::future< int >           f_int;

typedef std::shared_ptr< f_int >     f_int_ptr;
typedef std::vector< f_int_ptr >     f_int_vec;
```

std::future can't be copied, so it's stored using a shared_ptr for ease of use in a vector, but there are various solutions.

Next, an example of using these for 10 threads of work

```
void executive_function()
{
 // a vector of future pointers
 f_int_vec future_list;

 // start some threads
 for( int n=0; n < 10; ++n )
    {
     // a packaged_task calling func
     func_task  ft( &func );

     // get a future from the task as a shared_ptr
     f_int_ptr future_ptr( new f_int( ft.get_future() ) );

     // store the task for later use
     future_list.push_back( future_ptr );

     // launch a thread to call task
     std::thread( std::move( ft )).detach();
    }

 // at this point, 10 threads are running

 for( auto &d : future_list )
    { 
      // for each future pointer, wait (block if required)
      // for each thread's func to return
      d->wait(); 

      // get the result of the func return value
      int res = d->get();
    }
 }
```

The point here is really in the last range-for loop. The vector stores futures, which the packaged_tasks provided. Those tasks are used to launch threads, and the future is key to synchronizing the executive. Once all threads are running, each is "waited on" with a simple call to the future's wait function, after which the return value of func can be obtained. No mutexes or condition_variables involved (that we know of).

This brings me to the subject of processing files in parallel, no matter how you launch a number of threads. If there were a machine which could handle 10,000 threads, then if each thread were a trivial file oriented operation there would be considerable RAM resources devoted to file processing, all duplicating each other. Depending on the API chosen, there are buffers associated with each read operation.

Let's say the file was 10 Mbytes, and 10,000 threads began operating on it, where each thread used 4 Kbyte buffers for processing. Combined, that suggests there would be 40 Mbytes of buffers to process a 10 Mbyte file. It would be less wasteful to simply read the file into RAM, and offer read only access to all threads from RAM.

That notion is further complicated by the fact that multiple tasks reading from various sections of the file at different times may cause heavy thrashing from a standard hard disk (not so for flash sources), if the disk cache can't keep up. More importantly, though, is that 10,000 threads are all calling system API's for reading the file, each with considerable overhead.

If the source material is a candidate for reading entirely into RAM, the threads could be focused on RAM instead of the file, alleviating that overhead, improving performance. The threads could share read access to the contents without locks.

If the source file is too large to read entirely into RAM, it may still be best read in blocks of the source file, have threads process that portion from a shared memory resource, then move to the next block in a series.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but your "typical client wait example" is wrong, `cv` is not a "condition" it's a _condition variable_, but there should be a condition (i.e. a predicate) that you check before waiting on the condition variable, and when waking up again. A typical condition check would be "is there work available in the queue?". Correct use of condition variables requires a mutex, a condition variable, and the actual condition you test.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely, I partially agree with your point in that I've not had my second coffee yet, and I've not introduced the concept of condition vs condition_variable in the discussion. However, it is not universally true that a condition variable is required; that's an application level requirement. Events are that paradigm of a blocking call, waiting until signalled. The predicate is part of the client paradigm - which in the example above IS GIVEN, just not explicated...the condition there is the queue being empty!

Comment: Your example uses `std::condition_variable`, incorrectly. It has the same semantics as a [`pthread_cond_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html): _"When using condition variables there is always a Boolean predicate involving shared variables associated with each condition wait that is true if the thread should proceed. Spurious wakeups [...] may occur. Since the return from pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait() does not imply anything about the value of this predicate, the predicate should be re-evaluated upon such return."_  ...

Comment: ... In general the predicate must be evaluated while the mutex is locked, usually in a loop, which your example does not show. Your comments might be true of Windows events, but **not** `std::condition_variable`. Your answer shows a common anti-pattern of condition variable usage, and that's what I'm commenting on. See https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/condition-variable-spurious-wakes.html and https://goo.gl/v8pQzQ

Comment: @JVene, you are falling into the same trap as many before you. Conditional variables ARE NOT signaling mechanism. They have so-called spurious wake-ups - when your thread awakens without any signal from anybody else, just feeling well-rested already. If you do not check condition after you wake up, you will not know if it is time to really start your day, your still can spend some time in bed.

Comment: And if you don't check the predicate between locking the mutex and waiting on the condition variable you can miss a notification and go to sleep when you should really be doing work. These are common errors, but easily preventable if you just use them correctly ... which your example above **does not** do.